# Mozilla Firefox memory leak when resizing image slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I'm developing a website that requires simple slideshow with cross-fading of images.
Extracted portions can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/musicyeo/qaLhsr6t/18/

**Bug Repro Steps:**
Resize the browser (hence the images) back-and-forth quickly a few times.
Memory usage of Firefox starts to climb till 1.5 GB to 2 GB, until some images disappears. Console log: Image corrupt of truncated.
After closing browser, process is dangling.

Before the error appears, e.g., at below 1 GB or so, a one-time resize of the browser lowers and stabilizes memory usage to around 600+ MB or so.

**Affected Browsers:** Mozilla Firefox latest version (both 32 and 64 bits).

**Working Browsers:** Chrome and IE works fine without this problem. Memory consumption is comparatively low and stable.

Seems likes Firefox creates and stores in RAM multiple copies for each image, possibly of different dimensions during resize, and the "interim ones" are not released.
Or if I am not implementing slideshow the correct way, please enlighten me.

Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mainWrapper">
<div class="heroImg">
    <img class="resizable" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/25945/pexels-photo-25945.jpg">
    <img class="resizable" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/33092/domestic-cat-cat-adidas-relaxed.jpg">
    <img class="resizable" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/26919/pexels-photo-26919.jpg">
    <img class="resizable" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/106343/pexels-photo-106343.jpeg">
    <img class="resizable" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/29013/pexels-photo-29013.jpg">
    <img class="resizable" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/26880/pexels-photo-26880.jpg">
    <img class="resizable" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/106606/pexels-photo-106606.jpeg">
    <img class="resizable" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/105987/pexels-photo-105987.jpeg">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#mainWrapper { max-width: 996px; }

.heroImg {
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.heroImg img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    // Set the first image and fade it in
    $('.heroImg img:first-child').animate({opacity: 1.0}).addClass('frontImg');
    setInterval('showNext()', 2000);
});

function showNext() {
    var current = $('.heroImg img.frontImg');
    if (typeof current === undefined || current === null)
        current = $('.heroImg img:first-child');

    // Only transit image if current item is not animating
    if (current.queue('fx').length === 0) {

        // Get the next(wrapped-around) image
        var next = current.next();
        if (current.is('.heroImg img:last-child'))
            next = $('.heroImg img:first-child');

        // Fade in next image. Class frontImg has large z-index set in CSS.
        next.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('frontImg').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

        // Fade out current image
        current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000).removeClass('frontImg');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but with changing width and height properties of an image in Firefox. And still couldn't solve that.

But may try a transition with transition event to catch when it was finished.